# Some key events prevent others from firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, keyevent, piano

First, here's the live application I'm working on as a study: [turbo_synth](https://turbo-synth.netlify.app/)

I'm making it using VueJS, however, I believe the issue is unrelated to Vue.

**The issue:**
It all works fine and dandy, except when trying to play certain combinations of notes, for example, try playing the keys Q, W, and then 2. You'll notice the last note isn't being played and not even shown as pressed, while you could play Q, W, E, R and Y at the same time. So it doesn't seem like there is a limit, as I thought previously?

**The code:** I'm using vue-keypress to easily handle the key events globally.

Template part

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Basic oscillator test</h1>
        <label for="waveType">Choose a wave type:</label>

        <select
            name="waveType"
            id="waveType"
            v-model="wave"
        >
            <option value="sine">sine</option>
            <option value="square">square</option>
            <option value="triangle">triangle</option>
            <option value="sawtooth">sawtooth</option>
        </select>

        <hr>

        <ul class="keyboard">
            <li
                v-for="note in testBoard"
                :key="note.id"
                :class="[note.class, getKeyByValue(testBoard, note).charAt(0), {'pressed': pressedNotes.includes(note.freq)}]"
                @mousedown="playSound(note.freq, 1)"
            >
                <p>{{getKeyByValue(testBoard, note).replace('s', '#')}}</p>
                <p>{{String.fromCharCode(note.keycode)}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <Keypress
            v-for="note in testBoard"
            :key="note.id"
            key-event="keydown"
            :key-code="note.keycode"
            @success="playSound(note.freq)"
        />
        <Keypress
            v-for="note in testBoard"
            :key="note.id"
            key-event="keyup"
            :key-code="note.keycode"
            @success="removeNote(note.freq)"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

Script part:

```
<script>
import { noteValues, testBoard } from './assets/notevalues.js';
export default {
    name: 'App',
    data() {
        return {
            noteValues,
            testBoard,
            selectedNote: null,
            wave: 'sine',
            pressedNotes: [],
        }
    },
    components: {
        Keypress: () => import('vue-keypress')
    },
    methods: {
        getKeyByValue(object, value) {
            return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === value);
        }
        ,
        playSound(note, clicked) {
            if (this.pressedNotes.includes(note)) {
                return;
            } else {
                this.pressedNotes.push(note);
                const context = new AudioContext();
                const o = context.createOscillator();
                const g = context.createGain();
                o.connect(g);
                g.connect(context.destination);
                o.type = this.wave;
                const frequency = note;
                o.frequency.value = frequency;
                o.start(0);
                o.stop(context.currentTime + 1)
                g.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(
                    0.00001, context.currentTime + 2.5
                );
                setTimeout(() => {
                    context.close();
                }, 1000);
                if (clicked === 1) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.removeNote(note);
                    }, 50)
                }
            }
        },
        removeNote(note) {
            const index = this.pressedNotes.indexOf(note);
            if (index > -1) {
                this.pressedNotes.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

And here's the list of notes:

```
export let testBoard = {
  'C3': { keycode: 81, freq: 130.81, class: 'white' },
  'Cs3': { keycode: 50, freq: 138.59, class: 'black' },
  'D3': { keycode: 87, freq: 146.83, class: 'white' },
  'Ds3': { keycode: 51, freq: 155.56, class: 'black' },
  'E3': { keycode: 69, freq: 164.81, class: 'white' },
  'F3': { keycode: 82, freq: 174.61, class: 'white' },
  'Fs3': { keycode: 53, freq: 185.00, class: 'black' },
  'G3': { keycode: 84, freq: 196.00, class: 'white' },
  'Gs3': { keycode: 54, freq: 207.65, class: 'black' },
  'A3': { keycode: 89, freq: 220.00, class: 'white' },
  'As3': { keycode: 55, freq: 233.08, class: 'black' },
  'B3': { keycode: 85, freq: 246.94, class: 'white' },
  'C4': { keycode: 90, freq: 261.63, class: 'white' },
  'Cs4': { keycode: 83, freq: 277.18, class: 'black' },
  'D4': { keycode: 88, freq: 293.66, class: 'white' },
  'Ds4': { keycode: 68, freq: 311.13, class: 'black' },
  'E4': { keycode: 67, freq: 329.63, class: 'white' },
  'F4': { keycode: 86, freq: 349.23, class: 'white' },
  'Fs4': { keycode: 71, freq: 369.99, class: 'black' },
  'G4': { keycode: 66, freq: 392.00, class: 'white' },
  'Gs4': { keycode: 72, freq: 415.30, class: 'black' },
  'A4': { keycode: 78, freq: 440.00, class: 'white' },
  'As4': { keycode: 74, freq: 466.16, class: 'black' },
  'B4': { keycode: 77, freq: 493.88, class: 'white' }
}
```

I've also tried other people's pianos made with vue or different tech, and there's always a similar problem.
I might be missing something crucial, who knows, but I cannot find the info I need.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Are you sure it's not because you `return` in the first `if` block of `playSound`?

Comment: Yep, this block is only here to prevent the same note from being played over and over as long as the key is pressed. Even without it, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, and there's nothing you can do to fix it — this is a hardware limitation on many keyboards.

First, imagine the keyboard laid out as a rectangular grid (in other words, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, and <kbd>Z</kbd> are in the same column, even though they're usually not directly above one another).

The limitation is that no three keys that form three corners of a rectangle can be recognized at the same time. If you hold down two keys in a row, then a third key can't be in the same column as either of the first two. If you hold down two keys in a column, then a third key can't be in the same row as either of the first two. If you hold down <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>, then any key on the row starting with <kbd>A</kbd> will work fine, but <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>, etc. will all be locked out.

Alternatively, some machines might give you "ghost" keypresses at the fourth corner of the rectangle — holding down <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> and pressing <kbd>E</kbd> will register a keypress for <kbd>E</kbd>, but also one for <kbd>C</kbd> at the same time, even though nobody pressed <kbd>C</kbd>.

All of this has to do with the way keyboards are built electronically, and there's nothing you can do about it in software. There are some keyboards that don't have this limitation, but you can't count on your users to have them.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the swift response, have a good day!